# Changing SettingsFlyout Header style to allow long Title?

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm using the Win 8.1 `SettingsFlyout` in my app. Design has asked for several Entry Points (nomenclature from [Guidelines for app settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh770544.aspx)) with fairly long titles. These settings names work fine in the Settings Charm flyout (the one that lists all the entry points), but when the user drills into a specific flyout the title (as displayed in the header) gets truncated. This is especially painful in foreign languages, where any attempt to control the translation becomes a bureaucratic pain. The ~20 characters available is insufficient for what Design wants here.

Is there a way to change the style of the Header (or at least the Title) in my `SettingsFlyouts` so that the Title can be displayed on multiple lines?

Comment: You can [break it out](http://www.codeguru.com/win_mobile/win_store_apps/working-with-the-settingsflyout-control-in-windows-8.1.htm) and just slap textwrapping on it.

Comment: I don't understand how that link describes "breaking it out". Is this a standard XAML practice?

Comment: Yea, it's one of the cool benefits of templating so you can alter the look/feel of just about anything.

Comment: OK, sounds like it could work. I have no idea how to do that, though, and "break out" doesn't produce much in the way of useful search results. Can you (or anyone else with templating) throw together a quick answer describing the process?

Comment: Do you have Blend? It makes it generally a lot easier. It's not something someone will be able to cover quickly with a swift adhoc answer though, you'll probably want to do some different reading about [styles and templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465374.aspx), it will kickstart your imagination.